# How to define two relationships to the same table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, relationship

I’ve looked all over the SQLAlchemy tutorial and other similar questions but I seem to be struggling to get this join to work:

**The scenario**: I have a `pages` table represented by the `Page` model. Pages can be created by an user and edited by an user, but not necessarily the same one. My `Page` model looks like this (abridged):

```
class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    slug = Column(Text)
    title = Column(Text)
    direct_link = Column(Text)
    body = Column(Text)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    published_on = Column(DateTime)
    publishing_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    last_edit_on = Column(DateTime)
    last_edit_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    # Define relationships
    publish_user = relationship('User', backref = backref('pages', order_by = id), primaryjoin = "Page.publishing_user_id == User.id")
    edit_user = relationship('User', primaryjoin = "Page.last_edit_user_id == User.id")
    category = relationship('Category', backref = backref('pages', order_by = id))
```

My users are stored in the users table represented by the `User` model. As I said I’ve been all over the SQLAlchemy docs looking for this, I’ve tried to make it look as similar to their example as possible, but no to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure ive set it up right for what i want it to do. I want to be able to get a page from a query, and call page.publish_user to get the publishing user. Ive tried the suggestion below, but still no luck

Comment: You say it's not working, but can you be more specific -- an error, an unexpected return value, what? I don't see any obvious problems in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 31):

As of version 0.8, SQLAlchemy can resolve the ambiguous join using only the `foreign_keys` keyword parameter to `relationship`.

```
publish_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[publishing_user_id],
                                  backref=backref('pages', order_by=id))
edit_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[last_edit_user_id])
```

Documentation at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths

Answer (score 16):

I think you almost got it right; only instead of `Model` names you should use `Table` names when defining `primaryjoin`. So instead of

```
# Define relationships
publish_user = relationship('User', backref = backref('pages', order_by = id), 
    primaryjoin = "Page.publishing_user_id == User.id")
edit_user = relationship('User', 
    primaryjoin = "Page.last_edit_user_id == User.id")
```

use:

```
# Define relationships
publish_user = relationship('User', backref = backref('pages', order_by = id), 
    primaryjoin = "pages.publishing_user_id == users.id")
edit_user = relationship('User', 
    primaryjoin = "pages.last_edit_user_id == users.id")
```

Comment: this is probably the 20th sqlalchemy question you've helped me with

Answer (score 4):

Try `foreign_keys` option:

```
publish_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=publishing_user_id,
                                  primaryjoin=publishing_user_id == User.id,
                                  backref=backref('pages', order_by=id))
edit_user = relationship(User, foreign_keys=last_edit_user_id,
                               primaryjoin=last_edit_user_id == User.id)
```

Comment: When you add ``foreign_keys`` and join condition is deducible, there is no need to add ``primaryjoin`` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The example in this documentation
`http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths` isn't for one-to-many.... I think.
In the one-to-many case here's what worked for me:

```
class Pipeline(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pipelines'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
...

    input_resources = relationship("Resource", foreign_keys="Resource.input_pipeline_id")
    output_resources = relationship("Resource", foreign_keys="Resource.output_pipeline_id")

   ...


class Resource(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'resources'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
   ....

    input_pipeline_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("pipelines.id"))
    output_pipeline_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("pipelines.id"))

    ...
```