# Flask + SqlAlchemy retrieve a class object from another class attribute

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm building a `flask` application using `SqlAlchemy` and I'd like to retrieve the `author` from a `Notification` object from the `Notification` object itself, rather then parsing all `User`s to a `template` in order to capture the `author`'s data.

Here's my models:

In `app/models.py`

```
from app import db
from datetime import datetime

#...

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.Binary(72))
    notifications = db.relationship('Notification', backref='recipient', lazy='dynamic')

#...

class Notification(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    pending = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    author = ?
```

In my routes, I always parse the `notifications` from a `current_user` as an argument, as I use it in my `templates/base.html` navbar (and all my views `{% extends "base.html %}`)

Here's one route example:

In `app/routes.py`

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
        notifications = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first().notifications.all()
    else:
        notifications = []
    return(render_template('index.html', title=_('Home'), notifications=notifications))
```

But, I don't want to parse all the Users from the database in order to get the author information from each notification, instead I want to access the author User object in my template from the Notification object itself, like so:

In `app/templates/index.html`

`{{ notification.author.username }}`

And that should return its username.

What kind of relationship or trick would I have to do to achieve that?

P.S: Would that be in any way insecure as a user (a notification `recipient`) could somehow exploit it to access unwanted data from the `author`, such as `nothification.author.password_hash` for example? If so, what would be the best way to implement what I'm trying to?

## Edit

To clarify the question, as pointed by @noslenkwah, I'd like to make it clear that the `author` is a `User` and I hope that I can create a `Notification` object by assigning things as follows:

`notification = Notification(body='example', user_id=some_recipient_id, author = User.query.filter_by(username=some_author_username).first())`

I could then `db.session.add(notification)` and finally `db.session.commit()` it.

`some_recipient_id` is the `id` of a `User`, being an unique identifier and its `primary key` and `some_author_username` is also a unique identifier. 
I could also `filter_by(id=some_author_id)`, whereas `some_author_id` would be a `User`'s `primary key` and also a `unique` identifier.

Comment: What is the author? Is it a `User`? How is the author determined? Can it be easily defined when a `Notification` object is created?

Comment: Hi @noslenkwah, thanks for asking, I'll be updating the question. The author is a User and I'm hoping I can create a Notification object setting the author as an User, either from the flask shell, by running `not = Notification(body='something',user_id=some_integer,author=User.query.filter_by(id=some_integer).first())`, then I'll be running `db.session.add(not)` and `db.session.commit()`, alternatively  I'll be creating a `route` to create a `Notification` when running the app, with its own `template`, containing fields fill all the required attributes.

Comment: You can do that. Your answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548033/how-to-define-two-relationships-to-the-same-table-in-sqlalchemy) question

Comment: @noslenkwah , thank you very much for pointing to that question. I've managed to solve my problem reading the solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @noslenkwah pointing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548033/how-to-define-two-relationships-to-the-same-table-in-sqlalchemy) question, I was able to find a way to accomplish what I was trying to.

Here's how:

in `models.py`

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
from datetime import datetime

#...

class Notification(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'notification'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    pending = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    recipient = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[user_id],
                                      backref=backref('notifications', order_by=id, lazy='dynamic'))
    author = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=[author_id])
```